# html markup and standards + img element

Tags: html, performance, xhtml, standards, w3c

Is it a good idea / practice to specify the unit of measurement on img elements in html markup?

I've always done, and thought yes. I assume it avoids browser from guessing either % to px?

Maybe I am wrong here, and it's quicker, more efficient, and suggested, to simply specify numeral value without trailing UOM.

I've read through the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Images_in_HTML), and found nothing specific to my question.

```
<img src="/path/to/image/thegood.jpg" width="100px" height="100px" />
```

vs.

```
<img src="/path/to/image/andthebad.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
```

Comment: Or just use the style element + px.

Comment: @Thew That would be extraneous. Better practice and standard to initially specify as attribute and value specific to the img element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The spec specifically states](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/dtd.html#Length) the length without a percent indicates pixels.

```
<!ENTITY % Length "CDATA" -- nn for pixels or nn% for percentage length -->
```

Comment: Hi Rob, great! Exactly what I was looking for. _That being said, it's not all too clearly indicated, spec is somewhat difficult to make sense of._

Comment: With that being said, it still doesn't answer my question in terms of performance? I suppose I could run a test myself.

Comment: @Michel Joanisse - it says 'nn for pixels' so the 'px' is not needed for pixels. The spec won't state performance advantages since that's not their job.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use px as it preserves the image ratio as you intended. Width of 100% can stretch the image on a wide screen leading to a poor image!

Answer (score 0):

Performance wise, dont even consider it.

Otherwise if you'd want to restrict the image size, you should specify it. If you'd just want the fullsize image dont specify it at all. And where possible use CSS.

Comment: I disagree here, W3C specifically states the following: 'When the user agent finds an img element in the HTML, it starts loading the image the src attribute points to. By default, it doesn’t know the image’s dimensions, so it’ll just display all the text lumped together, then shift the rest of the document around when the images finally load and appear. This can slow down page loading ...' [http://www.w3.org/wiki/Images_in_HTML#Faster_image_display_by_defining_the_dimensions_using_width_and_height]

Answer (score 0):

You should always specify the images' measurement. When the browser loading your page, the screen will less flicker because the browser know the image sizes in advance.

So you #1 code is preferred:

```
<img src="/path/to/image/thegood.jpg" width="100px" height="100px" />
```